# Converting from decimal to non-decimal and printing(no strings, arrays and recursion)

Tags: c, base-conversion, non-recursive

Need help with a idea of how to convert a decimal number to non-decimal form(any, given by user input) and print it. The limitations are that arrays and strings are not allowed and while I wrote a recursive function for that, I am thinking of a non-recursive method for the same thing.

More of a personal challenge/exercise than anything vital/serious so feel free to tell me where to shove myself.

Note: I am working in C for this exercise.

Comment: Converting from one base to another is just a matter of formatting the number, which is truly always stored in binary. When you convert from a base to another, you just create a string to represent the number in a new base, so without using strings this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a number `x` in base `B` is represented as such:  ***x = a<sub>n</sub>B<sup>n</sup> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>B<sup>2</sup> + a<sub>1</sub>B + a<sub>0</sub>***, where *0≤a<sub>i</sub><B*.  Note that dividing `x` by `B` gives *a<sub>n</sub>B<sup>n-1</sup> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>B + a<sub>1</sub>* with remainder  *a<sub>0</sub> / B*.  In other words, ***x* mod *B =  a<sub>0</sub>*** (*mod* is short for *modulus*, which is the remainder after division).

Implemented as an algorithm:

```
var x    = POSITIVE_INTEGER
var base = POSITIVE_INTEGER2
while x > 0
    print(x mod base)
    x = x div base    // Where "div" is integer division, equivalent to math.floor(x/base)
                      // This way we are discarding a_0.
                      // Next iteration we will get a_1, then a_2, etc.
```

This will print the digits in the reverse order.

Workaround: Instead of modulating to get the least significant digit, we modulate to get the most significant digit.  We do this by noting that ***x - (x* mod *B<sup>n</sup>) = a<sub>n</sub>***, where `n` is the most significant digit.

```
var x    = POSITIVE_INTEGER
var base = POSITIVE_INTEGER2
var bn   // This is base**n, where `n` is the most significant digit.
while x > 0
    print(x - x mod bn) // Print out a_n
    x = x mod bn        // Discard a_n
    bn = bn / base      // Next iteration get a_(n-1), then a_(n-2), etc.
```

`bn` can be calculated as `base ** math.floor(math.log(x) / math.log(base))` or by doing

```
var bn = 1
while bn * base < x
    bn = bn * base
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining this line to me: "Using .n as subscript n,"

Also, I do have that math knowledge, my problem is printing the number in it's proper order after I convert it from decimal TO a non-decimal base. I's kind of the opposite direction of what you explained.
Thanks by the way.